# Xamarin "XamarinShellPackage" did not load correctly

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have hit a problem with the new free version of Xamarin.

What I was finding is that I could not use the Storyboard. Whenever I tried to look at Main.storyboard I got the following error message:

> Something went wrong - The iOS Designer Mac Agent is not available

And when I clicked “Start Designer Agent” on that same dialog it went away for a few seconds with a progress bar and then came back with the exact same error.

This was odd because I could run the project I have created and it ran fine on the emulator on the connected Mac so I was definitely connected to it. I could also debug the code fine as well. But I couldn’t edit the UI or the storyboard at all.

I contacted the Xamarin support email address and told them all of this and they suggested to update the various components thusly:

> To update Xamarin on the Mac open Xamarin Studio and click on:
>
> Xamarin Studio > Check for Updates...
>
> I would advise doing the same for Xamarin for Visual Studio:
>
> Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other > Check for
>   Updates...
>
> Please also ensure that Xcode is up to date and that you've launched
>   Xcode and accepted any agreements for any new version.

So I followed those instructions.

I checked on the Mac and the Xamarin Studio installation is up to date. I checked the Xcode on the Mac and it is the latest version. I went to do the update in Visual Studio for Xamarin and some things were out of date so I went through that update. I also rebooted afterwards and restarted Visual Studio.

Unfortunately it has made the problem much worse.

Previously I could at least open and run projects using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015. What I was unable to do was use the storyboard designer.

Now I cannot do anything with Xamarin as now when I try to run Visual Studio with a Xamarin project I get the following dialog several times:

> The XamarinShellPackage package did not load correctly.

As well as another similar dialog referring to “XamarinAndroidPackage” and now the solution in the solution explorer is unavailable for Xamarin projects and I cannot create a new one without getting these messages.

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 but that has not helped.

I have tried escalating this problem with Xamarin but the best they could suggest is posting here on Stack Overflow as the best way of getting support for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167176/3270038](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167176/3270038) worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the `.vs` folder from the root of the solution folder, that worked for me. Make sure VS is closed when you do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a straight forward case of having to clear you MEF component cache.

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to the following folder in Windows Explorer '%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache'
3. Delete the contents.
4. Reload your project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I have tried that but unfortunately it has not solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  We'll take this to email for now until I get to the bottom of it  :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried quite many including delete MEF, reinstall xamarin, even re-install visual studio. None of them work for my case.

Finally I uninstall xamarin, and install the previous version of xamarin, and it works again.